# Can you batch convert all your posts to community wikis?

Tags: support, community-wiki

Is there a way to bulk-convert all my posts to community wiki, without having to do so individually?

Comment: In theory you could flag all your posts one-by-one for moderator attention and request to make the post CW. In practice this would mean you made new "friends" within the moderator team ...

Comment: @rene I wasn't even aware that much was necessary and that's time consuming.  I thought you could change them into a community wiki yourself but sounds like I'm mistaken.  I beileve there's a checkbox for it when first posting.  Maybe it just doesn't matter?  Seems to me, knowing very little, that a CW would be preferred in this case.

Comment: Yeah, you can only make an answer CW from the start. Later on there are no options left but contact a mod. And questions always need a mod to turn it into CW . The few times I asked for a CW it was granted ...

Comment: I'm struggling to see the benefit of doing that. If you did delete your account for whatever reason the content can still be curated through regular edits I think?

Comment: @rene actually, users can make their answers community wiki (even accidentally) on each edit, the checkbox is still there on the right under the answer box.

Comment: @AndrewT. ah, didn't know that. But then you need to make an edit still. Only questions can't be made CW then.

Comment: @ivarni That's helpful, thanks.  I know what a wiki is, obviously, so it's naturally intuitive to me that a community wiki would be preferable.  If it's not, or totally irrelevant, then my question is moot.

Comment: I'm unsure what is the issue here. Is it [to convert deleted users' posts to CW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332446/241919)? Or is it to preserve the display name even after the user is deleted (which [has a counter-proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337971/241919))?

Comment: @AndrewT.  The question is regarding if a user can bulk-convert all their posts before account deletion to a community wiki.  And, I suppose, if that's even relevant or preferred.  I presumed it was.

Comment: If that's the case, I think mentioning "the display name reverts to the default" is irrelevant since that doesn't help the case (and I got distracted for that).

Comment: You can always use something like [AutoIt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) or a macro keyboard to do it. I did it with [a macro keyboard](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/keyboard-print-skips-keys/75525#75525) to empty my 700-item bookmark list (and got the URLs extracted to a text document). (With some imagination it is usually possible, for robustness, to find keyboard ways to get focus on particular elements on a web page.) There are probably even more suitable tools for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no one-click button to convert all your posts into community wiki.

Why would you want to do that before account deletion though? Is it to lower the rep threshold needed for other lower-rep users to edit your posts after you're gone from the site?

If you have a very good reason, we can probably whip up a userscript or get a dev involved.

Comment: I know nothing about rep threshholds.  Why do this?  Simply because it seems, intuitively in my head, that a community wiki would be preferable over a dead account.  Yes, I'm aware posts can always be edited.  But then I guess I'm scratching my head over why community wiki option exists.  I think what you're saying is there's no point in even doing so.

Comment: @Zer0 consider reading [the "edit community wiki" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) which might help to understand the purpose of it. In general case though, instead of editing, users are allowed (and usually expected) to post a new answer instead of piggybacking to an existing answer.

Comment: Thanks.  After reading that then yes, the intent would be to make all posts a community wiki (easier to edit, no need for rep).  Sounds like manually is the only way though.